# Effective way to update array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, javascript-objects

i have to  update an element in array object based on a condition. currently i am using forEach and based on condition i am applying calculation in that element. i want to know the easiest way to updating the array without for loop
below is my array

```
[{index:123,total:20,family:'mobile'},
{index:321,total:40,family:'mobile'},
{index:543,total:54,family:'mobile'}]
```

i want to update total with `total*2` for an element with index '321'in the above array
my array should look like below after executing logic

```
[{index:123,total:20,family:'mobile'},
{index:321,total:80,family:'mobile'},
{index:543,total:54,family:'mobile'}]
```

i am using below code

```
var selectedId = 321;
this.arrayList.forEach((element, indexval) => {
  if((element.index== selectedId){
    this.arrayList[indexval].total = element.total*2
  } 
});
```

can this be optimized so that i need not iterate the list

Comment: you need to `find` and then update it. so find does a loop until it is found

Comment: or you could have kept a Map with key as index and the object as value

Comment: unless you can get the index of the specific element from somewhere, you need to iterate the over array. You can add a `break` to exit the loop once you find the element.

Comment: @nullptr Suggesting a `break` in an implementation which currently uses `forEach` doesn't make too much sense, because you cannot break out of a `forEach`

Comment: `const elem = this.arrayList.find(({index}) => index===321); if (elem) elem.total*=2`

Comment: ah, my bad, for some reason, I thought they were using the for loop